# Why does the ask question link keep bouncing back on finishing the signup page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I have already signed up for like the zillionth time, but this "ask question" link keeps on bouncing back to "finish sign up".

What should I do?

Comment: Make sure you're signed up for the specific site you want to ask a question on. Each site in the SE family requires an independent account.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about that. Small problem with your account - looks like your profile on Mathematics didn't get updated to "registered" whereas the other ones did. Fixed that up now, so you should be all set.

Comment: Well, That's great. Thank you so much.